Frequency Companding
I have a theory question. I want to know if compressing and expanding audio frequencies is possible or perhaps already accomplished. As a point of reference, audio companding is a signal processing method used to improve signal-to-noise ratios (SNR) over a recording medium or transmission like radio. You compress the audio level for transmission and expand at the receiver. Dolby is one of many methods.
Here is where I am going. Roughly 30 years ago, commercial two-way radio manufacturers developed single-sided radios and used ACSSB modulation (Amplitude Companded Single Side Band) to compete with FM radios. It worked pretty well. The purpose was to extend the coverage area. Narrow band FM has a 12.5 kHz bandwidth while an SSB has 3 kHz, thus expanding the range significantly. You are concentrating more energy over a narrower bandwidth.
Narrow band FM and SSB have the same audio frequency bandwidth called Toll Quality at 300 Hz to 3 kHz. Think of the old copper telephone lines. It is good enough for speech but could use improvement. I want to compress audio frequencies from 50 Hz to 5 kHz into 300 Hz to 3 kHz.
Can it be done, and where would I look?

There is no such thing as "frequency companding" so the simple answer to your title question is "no". But there are certainly methods for reducing the bandwidth required to transmit an audio signal over radio. Let's clear up the terminology you've mixed up:

SSB -- single sideband (occasionally called SSBSC for single sideband suppressed carrier) is a modulation technique that reduces the RF signal bandwidth compared to traditional AM (amplitude modulation) and increases the transmission efficiency, but it does incur considerable cost to audio quality. It's basically a filtering technique that removes some of the audio information that's not necessary for understanding speech. It's horrible for music.

"Companding" is not a modulation technique; it's an audio processing method that compresses amplitude variations before transmitting/recording the signal, then expands them afterward. It doesn't reduce bandwidth, but allows transmission of a wider dynamic amplitude range of sound than would otherwise be possible for a given medium and signal-to-noise ratio. Dolby processing may include companding as well as other sophisticated techniques.

Once an audio signal is digitally encoded however, you can take advantage of more sophisticated compression algorithms that allow transmission of the signal over a fraction of the bandwidth required for the raw audio signal, and with much greater immunity to noise. Going into the various lossless and lossy algorithms is beyond the scope of this question. But in any case, this makes the answer "yes" -- with digital encoding, you could easily transmit a 50 Hz - 5 kHz audio signal over a 300 Hz to 3kHz channel.


